# Outputing Text to Python in in external window using Tkinter isn't working as intended

Tags: python, tkinter

I coded this to output a title to the a window in tkinter and when I run my code a window pops up but there is no text inside.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

#window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title ('Test')
window.geometry('300x150')

#title
title_label = ttk.Label(master=window, text= 'Test Test Test', font='Calibri 24')
title_label.pack()

#run
window.mainloop()
```

[image] `your text`

Comment: Try deleting the grave accent characters at the beginning and end.  Runs ok here after deleting these extra characters.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Try reinstalling Python downloaded from python.org.

Comment: I tried reinstalling python still doesn't work. Does this work for anyone else?

Comment: I ran it successfully in the Thonny editor on a Mac.

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly - but it clearly ISN'T the code that produced your screenshot (window title & dimensions are different), so that doesn't actually prove anything.

Comment: It worked for me. Are you using macos?